# Directions API transit times do not match with Maps Search

Tags: google-maps, map-directions

I'm trying to pull transit times from google directions API.

**My  transit travel duration (routes>>legs>>duration>>texts/values) do not match manually entered information on maps.google.com, although the directions given are the same.**

I've noticed in some cases directions API drops transfer time (when waiting to transfer from train to train), but other cases are far more ambiguous. The difference in transit time from the data pulled from transit and manually entered is as much as 20 minutes (API has always been less than, in my limited experience). Does anybody know why this happens/how to fix?

I've verified my time formula (for the time of arrival/departure) is correct (seconds since 1/1/1970 UST + x hours for time difference * 3600 + y hours for time in the future * 3600). Is there anything else I should look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For users with a business-license(I'm sure maps.google.com does have this license^^) the directions-API returns more accurate results  that will  reflect the current traffic-situation.